# What is the difference between App: React.FunctionComponent and App = (): React.FunctionComponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Trying to understand typescript at the moment.

What is the difference between:

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<CustomProps> = (props: CustomProps) => {
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
};
```

and:

```
const App = (props: CustomProps): React.FunctionComponent => {
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
};
```

The second one throws an error:

```
src/App.tsx:19:3 - error TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<CustomProps> = (props: CustomProps)
```

means that `App` is a type of `React.FunctionComponent<CustomProps>`

```
const App = (props: CustomProps): React.FunctionComponent
```

means that your `App` is the type of `any` because you didn't assign a type but it returns an object of type `React.FuctionComponent`

The error means that you return a `JSX.Element` and you said that the function return a `FunctionComponent`

The right code is :

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<CustomProps> = (props: CustomProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
};
```

In addition, you can see directly what type your function is returned if you writte nothing on the return type. Is you have VS code you can hover your mouse on your function and it will display what it returns thanks to the intellisense

Comment: In addition to this answer check https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/basic_type_example for more ts-react info